# What is the best SE community to ask technical questions related to Google My Business?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

What is the best SE community to ask technical questions related to [Google My Business](https://www.google.com/business/)?  Would it be Super User?  Or is such a topic outside the scope of SE's communities?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the question, of course, but the most likely SE site is [Web Applications SE](https://webapps.stackexchange.com).
They even have a [tag](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-my-business?mixed=1) for Google My Business.

It is off-topic for Super User. In their [Help Center](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) it mentions that (among others) the following is off-topic:

> websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress,

Google My Business falls in this category, so SuperUser is not the right site for questions about it.

Comment: Ah right, Web Apps--I forgot about that one. OK, that indeed sounds like the best option, and I'll note it for later.  FYI my question is a somewhat technical question about Google My Business:  am I able to add more than one business to my account, or do I have to create a separate account for each business.  I will post to Web Apps.